app crashes when opening from a deeplink and using sharedtransition api
when opening app using a deep link, eg, from notification or widget, it crashes with stacktrace at the bottom of question.
Link to Navigation route file https://github.com/ayitinya/english-dictionary-app/blob/351df21b136a9651440990f625aa8e99898aac7c/app/src/main/java/com/ayitinya/englishdictionary/navigation/Navigation.kt
@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun EnglishDictionaryNavHost(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    SharedTransitionLayout(modifier = modifier) {
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        NavHost(modifier = modifier,
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Home,
        ) {
            definitionScreen(
                sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout
            )

            homeScreen(
                sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout
            )

        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data object Home

fun NavGraphBuilder.homeScreen(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
) {
    composable<Home> {
        HomeScreen(
            sharedTransitionScope = sharedTransitionScope,
            animatedContentScope = this@composable
        )
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun HomeScreen(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope
) {
    Scaffold() { paddingValues ->
        LazyColumn(contentPadding = paddingValues) {
            item {
                    WordOfTheDay(
                        sharedTransitionScope = sharedTransitionScope,
                        animatedContentScope = animatedContentScope
                    )
                }   
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun WordOfTheDay(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        ) {
            
            with(sharedTransitionScope) {
                Text(
                    text = wordOfTheDay.word,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
                    modifier = Modifier.sharedElement(
                        sharedTransitionScope.rememberSharedContentState(key = wordOfTheDay.word),
                        animatedVisibilityScope = animatedContentScope
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Serializable
data class DefinitionRoute(val word: String, val isWotd: Boolean = false)

fun NavGraphBuilder.definitionScreen(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
) {
    composable<DefinitionRoute>(deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
        uriPattern = "app://com.ayitinya.englishdictionary/{word}"
    })) {
       
        DefinitionScreen(
            sharedTransitionScope = sharedTransitionScope,
            animatedContentScope = this@composable
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(
    ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class,
)
@Composable
private fun DefinitionScreen(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope
) {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            uiState.word?.let {
                TopAppBar(
                    sharedTransitionScope = sharedTransitionScope,
                    animatedContentScope = animatedContentScope
                )
            }
        },
        )

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
private fun TopAppBar(
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope
) {
    LargeTopAppBar(title = {
        
                    with(sharedTransitionScope) {
                        Text(
                            text = word, modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(4f)
                                .sharedElement(
                                    sharedTransitionScope.rememberSharedContentState(key = word),
                                    animatedVisibilityScope = animatedContentScope
                                )

                        )
                    }
                


# libs.versions.toml

compose-ui = "1.7.0-beta02"
material3 = "1.3.0-beta02"

ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui", version.ref = "compose-ui" }
ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics", version.ref = "compose-ui" }
ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling", version.ref = "compose-ui" }
ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview", version.ref = "compose-ui" }
ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest", version.ref = "compose-ui" }
ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4", version.ref = "compose-ui" }
material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3", version.ref = "material3" }

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Uninitialized LayoutCoordinates. Please make sure when using the SharedTransitionScope composable function, the modifier passed to the child content is being used, or use SharedTransitionLayout instead.
    at androidx.compose.animation.SharedTransitionScopeImpl.getLookaheadRoot$animation_release(SharedTransitionScope.kt:1058)
    at androidx.compose.animation.SharedBoundsNode.getRootLookaheadCoords(SharedContentNode.kt:79)
    at androidx.compose.animation.SharedBoundsNode.access$getRootLookaheadCoords(SharedContentNode.kt:75)
    at androidx.compose.animation.SharedBoundsNode$measure$1.invoke(SharedContentNode.kt:149)
    at androidx.compose.animation.SharedBoundsNode$measure$1.invoke(SharedContentNode.kt:147)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadCapablePlaceable$layout$1.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:223)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadDelegate.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:444)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LookaheadDelegate.kt:424)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:621)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:259)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentNode$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:1019)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentNode$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:1011)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadCapablePlaceable$layout$1.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:223)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadDelegate.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:444)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LookaheadDelegate.kt:424)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:621)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:259)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$LookaheadPassDelegate$placeSelf$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1506)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$LookaheadPassDelegate$placeSelf$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1499)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:503)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:502)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:258)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release$default(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$LookaheadPassDelegate.placeSelf-MLgxB_4(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1499)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$LookaheadPassDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1450)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place(Placeable.kt:618)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place$default(Placeable.kt:246)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowMeasurePolicy$placeHelper$1$1.invoke(Row.kt:196)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowMeasurePolicy$placeHelper$1$1.invoke(Row.kt:188)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadCapablePlaceable$layout$1.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:223)
    ......


I don't think it is possible to deep link using Shared Element Transition, because the animation needs to have the before screen dimensions and the after screen dimensions, to be able to animate between them. So, in case of deep link, after screen is launched directly.

@gtxtreme I understand it doesn't make a lot of sense doing that from a deeplink, but in this case, the transition works when moving from one screen to another. ideally, it should be ignored when it is coming from a screen with no common element, ie, from a deeplink.

I agree, you could file an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/344343033
